# P/Invoke coarsening

Tags: clr, pinvoke

I wonder whether .NET CLR supports P/Invoke coarsening.

For example if we have three subsequent P/Invoke calls that deal with blittable types:

```
Native.DrawPolygon(1.0f, 1.0);
Native.DrawPolygon(2.0f, 1.0);
Native.DrawPolygon(3.0f, 1.0);
```

then we could perform managed-to-unmanaged context switch for the whole block just once, instead of doing it pointlessly three times.

Comment: Not possible.  And there's little point, the marshaling is a minute fraction of the cost of drawing a polygon.  Or anything else you'd pinvoke if you do it right.

Comment: @Hans P/Invoke does a bit more than marshaling. For example, it changes the GC mode. "P/Invoke has an overhead of between 10 and 30 x86 instructions" -- not including marshaling. Quite a big overhead to do it over and over (60 pointless instructions in my example). Also in my case, polygons aren't drawn immediately, they're buffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the framework doesn't do this.  You would have to build your API to minimise the managed-to-unmanaged switches.